# MySQL - I'm trying to filter values between 1.1*min(value) and 0.9*max(value)

Tags: mysql, filter, max, min, having

I have a column ride_distance_km and I've tried the following:

```
SELECT ride_distance_km
FROM ride_data
HAVING ride_distance_km  BETWEEN 1.1*min(ride_distance_km) and 0.9*max(ride_distance_km);
```

Query is running, but I get 0 results which is false.

Tried WHERE instead of HAVING and query didn't run.

[image: ---exemplary data preview---]

Looking on the attached photo, I expect to filter out the 1.2km, 28.06km and 30.13km rides (for this specific data of course)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Hi Benny, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refrain from using images to communicate tables (or code). Copy-paste the data into your question directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Having` without `Group by` does not make sense **when** you are not using aggregate functions on the **complete expression**. `Having` is applied after the aggregation phase and *may* be used if you want to filter aggregate results.

`Having ride_distance_km BETWEEN ...` will not be able to determine which row value for `ride_distance_km` to consider for comparison! I *believe* that it is not Standard SQL, but due to (mis)feature of MySQL, it is allowed. However, there is no guarantee that it will give correct results (as explained above).

One approach would be to determine [`Min()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) values in a Derived Table. Then, we can utilize these aggregate values for further filtering inside the join `On` clause.

Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT rd.ride_distance_km
FROM ride_data AS rd 
JOIN 
(
 SELECT MIN(ride_distance_km) AS min_ride_distance, 
        MAX(ride_distance_km) AS max_ride_distance 
 FROM ride_data
) AS dt 
  ON rd.ride_distance_km BETWEEN 1.1*dt.min_ride_distance AND 
                                 0.9*dt.max_ride_distance
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I've got it now